# Can I access the text layout/shaping engine directly from NDK?

Tags: c#, android, android-ndk

I'm looking for a **native** solution on Android to do text-layout, hit-test, get text glyphs and do other common thing on text, just as what is provided in [Pango](http://www.pango.org/) and [DirectWrite](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368038.aspx).

I found that android uses [Harfbuzz](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/jni/android/graphics/HarfBuzzNGFaceSkia.cpp) and [FreeType](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/libs/hwui/font/CachedGlyphInfo.h) but I'm don't know details about how they are used in android framework.

My question is: Can I access the text layout/shaping engine directly from NDK?

I know it is possible to build `so`(shared lib) of *Harfbuzz*, *FreeType* and even *Pango* with NDK and use them in a Android app. But before that, I want to know if it's possbile to use the existing Harfbuzz and FreeType in android framework directly and **natively**.